# zookeeper example - distributed math calculation

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to learn zookeeper but all the tutorials and explanations are way too abstract for me have a clear view of how it could benefit my life, or, it is just another tool that is "awesome" but no one will ever use directly in real life.

I understand zookeeper is a "coordination tool", master, worker, assign task and a bunch of failure prevention staff. However, I have a very 'naive' real-world problem and wondering if zookeeper itself will help me solve it.

Say I have a big big file with many many lines of numbers, like below:

```
1000
23213
3231
4213
..
```

And the goal/output is to come up with another file, which contains the square of corresponding line.

```
1000^2
23213^2
...
```

I actually have a real-life use case that I implemented using python-flask server to distribute the work based on request from the workers but it is too fragile. Also I cannot easily track the failures. And I am wondering will zookeeper be the solution.

**Can any zookeeper expert help me write some example code to distribute this work to maybe 3 computers. And in the end, send the data back to the master.**

I totally understand it must be super easy to use map reduce or multithreading to make it happen but I am wondering would it be possible to just use zookeeper to show the idea that "zookeeper is a coordination tool".

Comment: Indeed, Zookeeper is a coordination tool, you are looking for a computation tool. Use MapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to use Zookeeper is by taking advantage of ephemeral nodes as locks so as to create a distributed work queue.

Workers browse a list inside ZK and attempt to create an ephemeral "lock" node.
If the attempt fails it means another worker has locked the node.
If the attempt succeeds the worker can do the operation (in your case do the math), and then write a new node and delete the old node.

The power of the ephemeral lock is that if the worker dies for whatever reason the connection is broken and ZK guarantees that the lock goes away automatically.